# Recover data files from corrupted linux partition

Tags: data-recovery

I have a dd image of a 1TB drive.
It has 8 partitions.
first 3 are ntfs
4 is an extended partition
5 is linux boot
6 is swap
7 and 8 are linux partitions used by users for various storage purposes.

all partitions are OK except for 7 and 8.
dumpe2fs is unable to find any superblocks on partitions 7 and 8.
fsck says:

```
e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb7
```

I tried to provide alternate superblocks with the -b option. No go, same error message from e2fsck.

I must also add that the drive has no hard errors of any kind.

When I run strings on partitions 7 and 8 I do see what look like
contents of user files, and strings of applications that belch user
debug info or error messages.

How can I recover these files?

Comment: how did u get the alternate superblocks, was it with `mke2fs -n /dev/sdb7` as per http://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/

Comment: as per this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks you might need to recover your data as per this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: Were there any error messages on the terminal or in the kernel log, when that `dd` image was created?

Answer (score 0):

+1 for having an image to work with.

My go-to solution for filesystem recovery is [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/download_stdr.php). It's relatively cheap and has a good reputation. You should be able to scan and get a feeling for what can be recovered at this point...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ddrescue?

http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html

I've recovered many a partition with it. It works on drive images quite well.

Comment: `ddrescue` is a tool for recovering from media errors. The question provides no evidence of media errors. Besides he already has an image.